# Shared Excel file: How to notify the user once someone else has changed a cell value?

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint, notifications, onedrive

I have an Excel file, which is shared via SharePoint, i.e. it is located in a OneDrive-folder and multiple persons in different departments are having it open continuously.
In order to enable macros they open the file not inside the browser, but inside the Excel application.

Now my question is, is there an event being fired when someone else is changing a cell to which I could react with a macro? For example I would like to run a sound once certain cells are being changed to a specific value.

I tried Worksheet_Change and Workbook_Sync, but they are not being invoked.
I see the other persons activites live once they happen, but I can't automatically react.

Any help is appreciated!

[image]

Comment: This Application-level event might fire: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.workbookafterremotechange   But it doesn't give the the location of the change, only which workbook was updated.

Comment: Great, thanks @TimWilliams . In fact there are the two events BeforeRemoteChange and AfterRemoteChange, so the changed location can be identified by comparing before/after.